# How to calculate shift hours in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have table like below where (I=In) and (O=Out):

`id |    date    |   time   | status | employee_id 
----+------------+----------+--------+-------------
  1 | 2015-07-01 | 11:00:00 | O      |           1
  2 | 2015-07-01 | 08:00:00 | I      |           1
  3 | 2015-07-01 | 16:00:00 | O      |           1
  4 | 2015-07-01 | 12:00:00 | I      |           1
  5 | 2015-07-02 | 16:30:00 | O      |           1
  6 | 2015-07-02 | 10:12:00 | I      |           1`

I want to calculate attendance grouped by date, employee_id and with shift hours like below:

`date    | employee_id |   min    |   max    |  delta

------------+-------------+----------+----------+----------
 2015-07-01 |           1 | 08:00:00 | 16:30:00 | 07:00:00      <--(shift)
 2015-07-02 |           1 | 10:12:00 | 16:30:00 | 06:18:00`

I don't know if it can be possible to do it in postgresql.

Appreciate your support and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your status is consistent, i.e. always comes in pairs you could do something like:

```
select dt, employee_id, min_tm, max_tm, sum(delta_tm)
from (
    select dt
         , employee_id 
         , min(tm) over (partition by employee_id,dt) as min_tm
         , max(tm) over (partition by employee_id,dt) as max_tm
         , tm - lag(tm) over (partition by employee_id,dt order by tm) delta_tm
         , status
    from t
) as u 
where status = 'O'
group by dt, employee_id, min_tm, max_tm;
```

Comment: I assumed max value 16:30 for 2015-07-01 was a typo in the expected output

Comment: Clean, fast and perfect. thanks a lot @Lennart. Apologize for my typo.